# Android heap corruption on USB receive

Tags: android, usb, heap-corruption

I'm trying to write a service that communicates with a USB device using USB Interrupt transfer. Basically I'm blocking on UsbConnection.requestWait() in a thread to wait for interrupts transfers in, then pass those to the activity using an intent.

I seem to be having problems when the USB devices sends me a largish number of interrupt packets in a row (about 50). It sometimes works but usually the app crash with a message of that flavor:

```
02-23 01:55:53.387: A/libc(8460): @@@ ABORTING: heap corruption detected by tmalloc_small
02-23 01:55:53.387: A/libc(8460): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadbaad (code=1), thread 8460 (pf.mustangtamer)
```

it's not always a malloc call that fails, I have seen several flavors of malloc (dlmalloc, malloc_small) as well as dlfree. In every instance I get a Fatal Signal 11 and a reference to 0xdeadbaad so somehow I am corrupting the heap.

It's not obvious from the heap dump what is causing the corruption.

Here is what I believe is the offending code (the problem only occurs when receiving many packets back to back to back):

```
    private class ReceiverThread extends Thread {

    public ReceiverThread(String string) {
        super(string);
    }

    public void run() {
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(BUFFER_SIZE);

        buffer.clear();
        UsbRequest inRequest = new UsbRequest();
        inRequest.initialize(mUsbConnection, mUsbEndpointIn);

        while(mUsbDevice != null ) {

            if (inRequest.queue(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE) == true) {
                // (mUsbConnection.requestWait() is blocking
                if (mUsbConnection.requestWait() == inRequest){
                    buffer.flip();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[buffer.remaining()];
                    buffer.get(bytes);

                    //TODO: use explicit intent, not broadcast
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RECEIVED_INTENT);
                    intent.putExtra(DATA_EXTRA, bytes);
                    sendBroadcast(intent);
                } else{
                    Log.d(TAG, "mConnection.requestWait() returned for a different request (likely a send operation)");
                }
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "failed to queue USB request");
            }
            buffer.clear();
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "RX thread terminating.");
    }
}
```

Right now the activity is not consuming the intents, I'm trying to get the USB communication to stop crashing before I implement that side.

I'm not seeing how the code above can corrupt the heap, possibly through some non-thread safe behavior. Only one request is queued at a time so I think "buffer" is safe.
My target is a tablet running JB 4.3.1 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing anything wrong with this either. You may want to try removing code from your loop and see if it still corrupts the heap to help you zoom on the offending area.

Remember that heap operations are usually delayed, the garbage collector doesn't run immediately,  so you could be corrupting it somewhere else, and it's only showing up in this loop because it is very heap intensive.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I removed the insides of the loop a bit at a time until everything from the buffer flip to the intent broadcast and it still crashes, although it takes longer now. I think your point about this loop exposing the problem but not necessarily creating it is right on. +1 on your answer but can't make it the accepted answer yet as I'm hoping others will pipe in with advice.

Answer (score 0):

try to use a larger heap size by setting android:largeHeap="true" in your application manifest.

Comment: I'll give that a try but wouldn't I get some kind of "out of heap" message rather than corrupted heap? I'm worried that using a larger heap will mask the problem temporarily but not solve it.

Comment: changing the heap size made no difference, still crashes in the same way

Comment: that's because largeHeap will affect the java heap, not the native heap that is being corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I would have asked these questions in a comment, but alas, not enough rep.

I see nothing directly wrong with the code above, but I would check the following:

1. What is BUFFER_SIZE? crazily, I've had *very* strange problems with UsbRequest.queue() for sizes greater than 15KB. I'm pretty sure that this wouldn't cause your heap corruption, but it could lead to weirdness later. I had to break my requests into multiple calls to queue() to do large reads.
2. Are you using a bulk USB endpoint? I don't know what your application is, so I cant say for sure if you should be using a bulk endpoint or not, but its the type of endpoint intended for large transfers.
3. Lastly, when I encountered this 0xdeadbaad problem (detected by tmalloc_large), it had nothing to do with the code I thought was at fault (the code near the malloc) - it was of course a threading issue in which I had JNI native code reading/writing the same buffers on multiple separate threads! Its only that it gets detected when malloc is called, as user3343927 mentioned.